# Why does subversion hang without any information?

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ubuntu-17.10

I tried to update some svn directories. But suddenly `svn` hangs without any output message.

I pressed `ctrl-z` and did a `ps aux | grep svn`. The svn process is hanging with `SL`.

What to do now? How to gain some error output?

I already tried to checkout some other repository, but this ended up in the same behavior.

Here is a full `ps aux | grep svn`:

```
    other     7910  0.0  0.3 136732 12316 ?        SL   Jun25   0:20 svn log ../tags/
    other     8004  0.0  0.3 136732 12332 ?        SL   Jun25   0:20 svn log ../tags/
    other     8090  0.0  0.2 136824 11804 ?        SL   Jun25   0:20 svn up
    other    17754  0.0  0.2 136824 11612 ?        SL   Jun25   0:20 svn up
    other    26844  0.0  0.2 136824 11856 ?        SL   Jun25   0:17 svn up
    other    27080  0.0  0.2 136824 11624 ?        SL   Jun25   0:18 svn up
    other    27150  0.0  0.2 136628  9988 ?        SL   Jun25   0:17 svn co http://mysvnhub.de/repos/myproject1
    other    27713  0.0  0.2 136628 10044 pts/8    TL   12:12   0:00 svn co http://mysvnhub.de/repos/myproject1
    other    31639  0.0  0.2 136608 10136 pts/8    TL   12:30   0:00 svn co http://mysvnhub.de/repos/myproject1
    other    32207  0.0  0.0  14780  1016 pts/8    S+   12:38   0:00 grep --color=auto svn
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had a talk to a Linux expert who was inhouse for a while. He had a look to this issue and solved the problem. Here is what I understood so far:

He made a `strace` to the `svn up` call which showed that the process was hanging while polling for some file on D-Bus. This file has something to do with Ubuntu's keyring. After disabling the password store in the subversion config everything working pretty fine.

To disable the password store I used [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206604/svn-and-gnome-keyring#206609):

> Edit the `~/.subversion/config` with `gedit` or `nano` , and add the following
>
> ```
> [auth] 
> password-stores =
> ```
>
> then save and try again.

Comment: omg .... you saved me ... after 4 hours of loosing my mind .... Thanks ! :)